# Replace last index of , with and in jQuery /JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, replace

i want to replace the last index of comma (`,`)in string with `and`.

eg . `a,b,c` with `'a,b and c'`

eg   `q,w,e` with `q,w and e`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Jndsc/1/)

`lastIndexOf` finds the last index of the parameter string passed in it.

```
var x = 'a,b,c';
var pos = x.lastIndexOf(',');
x = x.substring(0,pos)+' and '+x.substring(pos+1);
console.log(x);
```

you can also use this function

```
function replace_last_comma_with_and(x) {
    var pos = x.lastIndexOf(',');
    return x.substring(0, pos) + ' and ' + x.substring(pos + 1);
}
console.log(replace_last_comma_with_and('a,b,c,d'));
```

**An alternative solution using regex:**

```
function replaceLastCommaWith(x, y) {
  return x.replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, " " + y + " ");
}
console.log(replaceLastCommaWith("a,b,c,d", "and")); //a,b,c and d
console.log(replaceLastCommaWith("a,b,c,d", "or")); //a,b,c or d
```

Answer (score 8):

This regex should do the job

```
"a,b,c,d".replace(/(.*),(.*)$/, "$1 and $2")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
var x= 'a,b,c,d';
x = x.replace(/,([^,]*)$/, " and $1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var str = 'a,b,c', replacement = ' and ';
str = str.replace(/,([^,]*)$/,replacement+'$1'); 

alert(str)
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/PgzrU/64/)

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop will help you out

first find the index of all , in your string using,

```
var str = "a,b,c,d,e";
var indices = [];
for(var i=0; i<str.length;i++) {
    if (str[i] === ",") indices.push(i);
}


indices = [1,3,5,7] as it start from 0

len = indices.length()
str[indices[len - 1]] = '.'
```

This will solve your purpose.